# Google Chrome не подгружает css и js

Tags: google-chrome, браузер

Обновился до версии Версия 53.0.2785.143 m и после этого появились проблемы с работой браузера:

При посещении сайтов бывает что хром не подгружает файлы **.css** и **.js**. На некоторых сайта, как stackoverflow, это лечится 2-3 перезагрузками сайта. На некоторых не лечится вообще :(

Пробовал те же сайты с этой же машины но через другие браузеры (Chromium, Vivaldi) - все прекрасно работает.

UPD: Картинки тоже грузятся через раз

Comment: Вы уверены что проблема вызвана именно Хромом?
Не вызвано ли это нестабильной работой роутера, провайдера, или средства защиты?
Ещё может быть это фильтры какого-нибудь дополнения, например, который режет рекламу.
Попробуйте отключить все дополнения и плагины в хроме, а также попробовать Firefox.

Comment: Ну я пробовал же другие браузеры, в них проблем нету. Значит проблема в Хроме. Расширения стоят все те же, что и раньше.

Comment: Отключил все расширения, ничего не изменилось